# Euler-Mascheroni constant trivial

Tags: calculus, integration, euler-mascheroni-constant

> Demonstrate the following trivial equation:
>
> $$\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log x \log y}{\sqrt{xy}} \cos(x + y)dxdy = (\gamma + 2 \log 2) \pi^2$$
>
> where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

**Proposed by Wan Lang Zonneveld**

This seems to me to be a matter of symmetry.

Comment: Quite a well known integral (so it's probably re-proposed): [Double Integral $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{\log x \log y}{\sqrt {xy}}\cos(x+y)\,dx\,dy=(\gamma+2\log 2)\pi^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791372/double-integral-int-0-infty-int-0-infty-frac-log-x-log-y-sqrt-xy-co)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about solving it by symmetry, but here's one approach (provided you know $\psi\left(\frac12\right)=-\gamma-\ln 4$):$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\exp-ixdx&=\Gamma(s)i^{-s}=\Gamma(s)\exp\frac{-\pi is}{2}\\\implies\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\exp-ix\ln xdx&=\left(\psi(s)-\frac{\pi i}{2}\right)\Gamma(s)\exp\frac{-\pi is}{2}\\\implies\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\exp-ix\ln xdx&=\left(\gamma+\ln 4+\frac{\pi i}{2}\right)\sqrt{\pi}\exp\frac{-\pi i}{4}.\end{align}$$
Your integral is the real part of the square of this, i.e. $\pi^2(\gamma+\ln 4)$.